# Is there a difference between 'data structure' and 'data type'?

Tags: language-agnostic

Two of the questions that often come up in the Uni exam, where I study, are:

Define data types. Classify and explain datatypes

Define data structures. Classify and explain data structures

Somehow, aren't they the same thing ?
Consider that you are making a `Tree<E>` in Java. You'd declare your class for `Tree<E>`, add methods to it and somewhere you would do `Tree<String> myTree = new Tree<>();` to make a tree object.

Your data 'structure' is now a data 'type'.
Say if you were asked a question: **Of what type is the variable myTree?** The answer would be, `Tree<E>`. Your data 'structure' is now a data 'type'.

Now since they are the same, they will be classified in the same way depending on what basis you want to classify them on. Primitive or non primitive. Homogeneous or heterogeneous. Linear or hierarchical.

That is my understanding. Is the understanding wrong ?

Comment: A type can be an `int`, which doesn't necessarily have a "structure". In fact, a type system is a kind of error checking system, which doesn't have much to do with "data structures" at all.

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if you find it satisfactory. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would like to correct the following to start - you created a **class** called "Tree" and an **object** called "myTree", not a **variable** called "myTree" of **datatype** "Tree". These are different things.

The following is the definition of a data type:

> A data type or simply type is a classification identifying one of various types of data, 
>       such as real-valued, integer or Boolean, that determines the possible values for that type; 
>       the operations that can be done on values of that type; the meaning of the data;
>       and the way values of that type can be stored.

Now, [as per Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type#Definition_of_a_.22type.22), there are various definitions for "type" in data type.

The question you have asked is a good one. There are data types in today's modern languages, that are referred to as **Abstract Data Types** or ADT in short. The definition of an ADT is:

> An abstract data type (ADT) is a mathematical model for a certain class of data structures that have similar behavior; or for certain data types of one or more programming languages that have similar semantics. An abstract data type is defined indirectly, only by the operations that may be performed on it and by mathematical constraints on the effects (and possibly cost) of those operations.

It is also written that:

> Abstract data types are purely theoretical entities, used (among other things) to simplify the description of abstract algorithms, to classify and evaluate data structures, and to formally describe the type systems of programming languages. However, an ADT may be implemented by specific data types or data structures, in many ways and in many programming languages; or described in a formal specification language.

Meaning that ADT's can be implemented using either data types or data structures.

As for **data structures**:

> A data structure is a particular way of storing and organizing data in a computer so that it can be used efficiently.

Many textbooks, use these words interchangeably. With more complex types, that can lead to confusion.

Take a small example: it's something of a standard to use b-tree for implementation of databases. Meaning, we know that this type of ADT is well suited for such type of a problem and can handle it more effectively. But in order to inject this effectiveness in an ADT you will need to create a data structure that will give you the desired output.

Another example: there are so many trees like b-tree, binary-search tree, AA tree, etc. All these are essentially of the type of a tree, but each one is in it's own a data structure.

Refer: [List of data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures) for a huge list of available structures.

Comment: `we know that this type of ADT`. I'm confused, is B-tree a ADT or a data structure? The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) says its a data structure, bu t you seem to imply its an ADT? I guess you could say B-trees are the data structure, and Trees are the ADT?

Answer (score 1):

The distinction is between *abstract* and *concrete* data structures. Some CS textbooks refer to abstract data structures as "data types", which is confusing because not all data types are data structures. They use "data structure" to specifically mean a concrete data structure.

An abstract data structure, also called an abstract data type, is the *interface* of the data structure. Java often represents them using interfaces; examples are `List`, `Queue`, `Map`, `Deque`, `Set`. (But there are others not represented in Java, such as bags/multisets, multimaps, graphs, stacks, and priority queues.) They are distinguished by their behavior and how you use the data structure. For instance, a set is characterized by forbidding duplicates and not recording order, whereas a list allows duplicates and remembers the order. A queue has a restricted interface that only lets you add to one end and remove from the other.

A concrete data structure is an implementation of an abstract data structure. Examples are `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`. These are both implementations of lists; while their list interface is the same, the programmer might still care about their different performance characteristics. Note that `LinkedList` also implements `Queue`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, there exist data structures in programming languages that have no type system. For example, you can modell a `Map` in LISP, or have a dictionary in Python. It would be misleading to speak of a type here, as *type* does IMHO only make sense with respect to some type system, or as an abstract concept like "the set of all values that inhabit t".

So, it seems that `data structure` has a connotation of an concrete implementation of some abstract type. If we speak of some object in a programming language with type system, OTOH, we would probably say that "it has type XY".

Comment: Python certainly has a type system.  Every value has a type.  Of course, Python *identifiers* can be assigned values of any type.